# Sorting only one column of a file

Tags: file, bash

I have a file like this

```
/device/000:004:00.7/vmkname = "vmnic8"

/device/000:005:00.0/vmkname = "vmnic0"

/device/000:005:00.1/vmkname = "vmnic4"

/device/000:005:00.2/vmkname = "vmnic10"

/device/000:005:00.3/vmkname = "vmnic11"
```

.... 15 lines

I want to change it like this:

```
/device/000:004:00.7/vmkname = "vmnic0"

/device/000:005:00.0/vmkname = "vmnic1"

/device/000:005:00.1/vmkname = "vmnic2"

/device/000:005:00.2/vmkname = "vmnic3"
```

...till

```
/device/000:005:00.3/vmkname = "vmnic15"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe 's/\d+(")$/$i++.$1/e;' file
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/O3J2c)

Answer (score 2):

Awk version :

```
awk '{if ($1) {print $1, $2, "\"vmnic"c++"\""}else{print}}' FILE
```

you can redirect output to a new file.

Comment: simplified version `awk 'NF{print $1, $2 " \"vmnic"c++"\""} !NF;' FILE`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
count=0
for i in `cat input_file.txt | cut -d " " -f1`
do
    echo $i = \"vmnic$count\" >> output_file.txt
    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Just make sure your input_file.txt doesn't have any empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

See :

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
while read a b; do
    [[ "$a" ]] || continue
    echo "$a = \"vmnic$((c++))\""
done < FILE > NEW_FILE
```

Comment: What's the problem to downvote that working smart snippet ? =)  Did you forget to replace FILE with your real file ? :/

Comment: Ah ok, I missed to deal with empty lines, but I have had edited my snippet to deal with...